# After $scope.$on('$destroy', eventName) scope not available second time

Tags: angularjs

To avoid repeated calls in emit, I am using 
$scope.$on('$destroy', eventName);

or

```
var eventName= $rootScope.$on("load_emit_data", function(event){
        $scope.getdata();   
        event.preventDefault();
        eventName()
    });
```

by this I can able to avoid the repeated calls, But my problem is

1. I want to refresh the dashboard after adding the record
2. After adding the first record dashboard refreshed successfully, call went once only.
3. but after destroy or eventName(), If I add second record, Emit is not calling..

can any body suggest ?

Comment: can give little more insight ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an AngularJS expert, but I wouldn't expect anything to survive after begin destroyed (at least till 'destroy' has a meaning).

Anyway [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) says:

> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.

ans also:

> Just before a scope is destroyed, a $destroy event is broadcasted on this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler that will give it a chance to perform any necessary cleanup.

So I would say that what you're experiencing is not a malfunctioning, it's *by design*.

Comment: I fixed the issue with destroy like this

var eventName= $rootScope.$on("load_emit_data", $scope.getdata);
    $scope.$on('$destroy', eventName);